# fixing the background image for a game I'm making using HTML

Tags: html, css

It's me again with another new project for finals.

I'm trying to make a game with HTML and I'm in the middle of making the main menu right now and I'm stuck on it.

The background image wouldn't fit in right and I've searched and tried every solution I can find in the internet but it just wouldn't come out right.

[Here's what it looks like. As you can see, it doesn't fit in right. I was trying to make the bg image fit in without having to scroll. I used a 1920x1080 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQv8G.png)

```css
body {
  background-image: url("main menu bg.png");
   background-size:     contain;                     
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center top; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel = "stylesheet"
   type = "text/css"
   href = "stylemenu.css" />
<title> Trio of Battles </title>
</head>
<body>
<button button style="background-color: transparent;" onclick="myFunction()"><img src="start button.png"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example? What do you mean with "wouldn't fit in right"?

Comment: just updated my question! The interface is new to me and it seems like it updated from when i first tried it

Comment: Try removing "background-size: 100% 100%;" and changing the lower background-size to "background-size: cover".

Comment: thanks so much for your answer! Unfortunately, it still won't come out the way I want it to. The image became bigger and stretches

Comment: "Background-size: auto" should display the image in it's normal resolution.

Comment: _“I was trying to make the bg image fit in without having to scroll.”_ - a _background_ image can not influence the dimensions of the element it gets applied to - so those scroll bars you have there must come from something else to begin with. We don’t know how big your start button image is that you put in the body as an actual `img` element - if no additional styles apply, then that is probably the culprit?

Comment: thank you for these! auto unfortunately doesn't work as expected but the scroll part is gone now after i removed my start button!

Comment: oh! I managed to fix it! thanks again! I used contain and set a min-height. I'll see if the buttons will work alongside this thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing body height to 100vh, you make sure that there's no scrollbar. And with contain, the image will always fit inside the screen.

```
body {
    background: url("main menu bg.png")no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: contain;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;

}
```